# VSCode + Flutter => quickfix leaves cursor on wrong line

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When using the quickfix / lightbulb / `Ctrl` + `.` feature to invoke `Wrap with widget...` the cursor ends up on the line below the inserted `widget`, forcing me to go up and select it every time to type in the new widget.

[image]

I am fairly certain it *used to* have `widget` selected automatically so you could just start typing the name of the new widget, however I can't find any settings in VSCode related to this and my searching has only brought up people asking how to invoke the quickfix menu.

**Update**:
This same behaviour happens when using the predefined actions like `Wrap with Center`, in that the cursor is down a line below the new `Center` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that this used to highlight `widget` and stopped. It was due to a limitation of the LSP protocol (which the Dart extension is migrating to).

This has been [recently resolved](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3143) by implemented an unofficial extension to LSP, however it required changes in both the Dart VS Code extension the LSP server (which ships in the SDK) and therefore requires updated versions of both before you'll see the fix.

If you're still seeing the cursor go to the wrong location for *other* fixes, please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code.

Comment: Right you are, I have been enjoying this fix and forgot to update this question. Thanks for all of your hard work Dan! <3